# Add some block to product view page through module xml file Magento

Tags: xml, magento, module, block, inject

Hi i am developing a simple extension  in which

i need to insert a new block on product page through xml file. Below is the xml file of my module

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
      <total_index_index>
          <reference name="root">
             <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns right.phtml</template></action>
           </reference>

           <reference name="content">
                  <block type="total/prototal"  name="total_prototal" template="total.phtml" />
                 </reference>
      </total_index_index>
</layout>
```

In this, layout is working on module **index** action and the content of **total.phtml** file is visible. I need to insert the content of total.phtml on product page.

So please suggest me how can i inset this on product page through xml.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you need to add `total_prototal` block under product view block ?

Comment: yes it can be below the cart button or above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="alert.urls"> 
            <block type="total/prototal"  name="total_prototal" template="total.phtml" />  
        </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

make sure this line must be exist in view.phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I am doing the same thing but my custom block is not rendering under "alert_urls" block. I want to show few extra information just after product name and price on product view page. Is there any other solution to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have file and folder in your design like this

```
/template/total/prototal.phtml
```

In your local.xml you can add like below

```
<catalog_product_view>
     <reference name="product.info">
           <block type="core/template" name="total_prototal" template="total/prototal.phtml" after="product.info.addtocart"/>
      </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Now in your `catalog/product/view.phtml`, call your custom block

Before

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
```

Add

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('total_prototal') ?>
```

Comment: i dont want to edit the view file. It  should add automatically

Comment: If you add any block, you need to call it in your phtml file.You need to tell Magento where to place it

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy that's not true. You can add blocks to a `core/text_list` and not have to render them manually