# how to add custom block before product tag on product view page in layout xml in magento?

Tags: xml, magento, layout, block, product

I want to add my custom block before product tag or after product description on product view page in magento. I used below code but it doesn't work:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="module/block" after="product.description"
          name="example_block" template="module/example.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something here.

By using the above code it doesn't add a block inside product view page. Have a look below

```
 <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

Note that you are adding outside the block "catalog/product_view". I think this is your problem.Now for solution you need to add your block inside the block "catalog/product_view".I think overiding the catalog.xml file to your theme and adding there should work but if you like to add it from another layout file than have a look on the link below

[Add some block to product view page through module xml file Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757335/add-some-block-to-product-view-page-through-module-xml-file-magento)

Hope this will be helpful.