# How to insert html code between product name and short description by observer module

Tags: php, xml, magento, module, block

I write module with some price manipulation. But now I need insert div block between product name and short description in product view and catalog list. Can I do this in my module? How I can do this by modify my module? Module that I write based on this

Shusha_Clockdown.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> <config>
> <modules>
>     <Shusha_Clockdown>            <active>true</active>
>         <codePool>local</codePool>
>         <depends>
>             <Mage_Catalog />
>         </depends>
>     </Shusha_Clockdown>
> </modules> </config>
> ```

Observer.php

> ```
> <?php
>  class Shusha_Clockdown_Model_Observer {
>   public function changeprice($observer) {
>
>       $event = $observer->getEvent();
>       $_product = $event->getProduct();
>           // добавляем доллар к простым продуктам
>           if ($_product->getSuperProduct() && $_product->getSuperProduct()->isConfigurable()) {
>       } else {            
>           $_product->setFinalPrice(50);
>       }
>
>       return $observer;
>   }
>  }
> ```

For generating html i use module.phtml and I don't know where it must be stored.

I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757335/add-some-block-to-product-view-page-through-module-xml-file-magento), add to xml, store my .phtml in folder - /app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/catalog/product, but no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add blocks (one after another) right in the observer, you can use the following method: 
create an observer in the config.xml of your extension: 
https://gyazo.com/69b8050ce3c7f1f2f11d874895791b68

Add a method in the observer:
https://gyazo.com/11db8562a9eb3d874cc0ac8c4d01ba0d

Next, in your block and its template, you add what you need (I just have a text tag there).
https://gyazo.com/b13f7efb93694d77c0c3c2046617529a

The result will be: 
https://gyazo.com/25356b81fb20891b3da3fc53a1cafd5c

As for disadvantages, perhaps the biggest one will be the difficulty of finding the place to add this code. Also note, that the price block doesn't have its own name in the layout, hence, this method will add its own custom block after every price block.

Thus method should only be used if there are no other options to change the template and the layout. If you can edit the product template, just insert your block in there and add it via your extension layout.